# Dates not accurate on seaborn x-axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot dates on seaborn. And I'm running into the problem that the tickers don't correspond to the actually dates, eg the x-axis variable. I like that it's readable and not overcrowded with information; but first and foremost, it needs to be accurate.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
import seaborn
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


g1 = seaborn.lineplot(test["ts"], test["hourly_revenue"], color="r")
g1.set_xticklabels(test["ts"], rotation=45)           
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

This is what test['ts'] actually looks like

```
0     2022-06-09 05:00:00
1     2022-06-09 06:00:00
2     2022-06-09 07:00:00
3     2022-06-09 08:00:00
4     2022-06-09 09:00:00
              ...        
223   2022-06-13 19:00:00
224   2022-06-13 20:00:00
225   2022-06-13 21:00:00
226   2022-06-13 22:00:00
227   2022-06-13 23:00:00
Name: ts, Length: 228, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And hourly revenue

```
0       15.69
1      137.31
2      155.32
3      158.52
4      132.55
        ...  
223    147.57
224     90.15
225     84.58
226     53.00
227     43.05
Name: hourly_revenue, Length: 228, dtype: float64
```

What can I do to fix this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988385/seaborn-plot-wrong-dates-on-x-axis) looks mildly related but it's overly specific to the asker's local data constraints/context.

Comment: You might want to use https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html instead, so you can specify the ticks and labels

Comment: `g1 = sns.lineplot(x=test["ts"], y=test["hourly_revenue"], color="r")` `ticks = test["ts"].to_list()[::10]` `_ = g1.set_xticks(ticks, ticks, rotation=90)`